# How to overcome seminar boredom

Tags: emotional-responses, seminars

I find I am frequently uninterested in the weekly seminars in my faculty, which consists of applied mathematics, fluid dynamics, and computer science.  My niche is a small sliver between applied maths and CS.

I know it's valuable to hear talks on things completely unrelated to what you do-- you never know what you'll learn-- but mostly what happens is that I see the first few slides, get bored and/or overwhelmed by too many foreign ideas, and then tune out and work on my own research.  In theory, I know that asking questions helps with engagement, but when a topic is too foreign, I would need to ask questions every slide to properly follow, and that would just be disruptive.  I then wonder why I bother attending at all, but the church-like culture surrounding the weekly seminars (i.e., "you have to go because someone with more power strongly suggests it") keep me there.

How can I get more out of these seminars that I'm obligated to attend?  (Note that responses like "Suck it up" or "Get over it, we all go through this" are not welcome-- I've found that this kind of approach just leads to acrimony.)

Comment: @Coder I didn't see that question when I posted, but yeah, lots of good tips there.  I would argue the focus of my question is different-- I assume in good faith that the speaker is doing the best they can, and the problem is largely me getting bored and bitter.  I would otherwise delete the question, but since it has answers, I will probably have to accept another shameful "close"...

Comment: I don't think anyone in this community can counsel you to feel good during presentation. You have to build interest in the presentation. That's all.

Comment: @Coder Well, the question wasn't asking for counseling to "feel good" during a presentation.  As most questions here, it was asking for practical tips.

Answer (score 1):

I sympathise with your predicament, and I certainly would not suggest that you need to "suck it up".  In fact, I would probably go even further --- your persistence to the contrary notwithstanding, the vast majority of math presentations at university ---particularly those delivered by students--- are barely watchable, and they are quite often a waste of their audience's valuable time.*  If you find that you are bored and/or overwhelmed in the first few slides, this suggests to me that *the presenter* is doing a bad job motivating interest in their topic, and keeping audience context in mind.  That is entirely consistent with my experience viewing mathematical presentations in university seminars; by and large, the quality of these presentations is abysmally low, and fundamental presentation problems are ubiquitous.

One of the most common problems I have observed with mathematical presentations is that they often tend to cram in too much material, and then overwhelm the audience by going too fast through specialist material that is unfamiliar to the audience.  It is common to observe "flashers" who put up walls of definitions, equations, derivations, etc., and then rush over them to try to make their talk fit into the allocated time.  Often the presenter makes no effort to motivate interest in their topic, and just assumes that the mere presence of an audience vitiates any obligation to be interesting.  In these cases, the audience gets lost after the first few slides, or bored, and then simply tunes out.  That is not the fault of the audience member --- it happens because the presentation is a steaming pile of shit.  If you attended a rock concert, or a comedy night, the presenters would know that it is their job to make you interested, and make sure the audience can follow along with the material.  Mathematics presenters often have not learned this lesson.

So, my advice: if you are compelled to go and see crappy presentations that fail to motivate your interest, and lose you within the first few slides, use that boredom as motivation to *improve your own presentations*, and make sure you are not subjecting others to the same boredom and bewilderment that you are being forced to endure.  Scrutinise each presentation with a critical eye and note the things that the presenter is doing wrong.  (Here is a related answer with some suggestions for [how to give a good presentation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/105179/105190#105190).)  Did the presenter motivate your interest in the topic?  Is he/she enthusiastic about the material?  Has the presenter provided a "hook" that caught your interest?  Did the presenter explain the material to you nice and slowly so that you could follow along?  Did the presenter limit their definitions and notation to what you can reasonable remember as you follow along, or did they overwhelm you with definitions and notation?  Did the presenter rush through something you didn't understand?  Did the presenter flash up a "wall of algebra" for a microsecond and then move on to the next slide?

One final note on this issue is your mention of the fact that your own specialty area is quite narrow, and you have trouble following along with presentations on foreign areas.  That is very common, and again, it is generally the fault of the presenter.  For that reason, when you come to give your own presentation, make sure you put yourself in the shoes of someone who has no knowledge of your specialty topic, and no interest in it.  Realise that it is *your job* to motivate their interest in what you are saying --- start strongly and make them (internally) say "wow!" and make sure your presentation gets them paying attention.  Simplify your problem and obey the crow epistemology (people can remember three things).  Take your audience on a nice slow journey through your topic, that is interesting, and so simple that they think your work is trivial.  Good luck!

---

...except to the extent that they are practice for the students.  Often we hold seminars of student presentations to give students practice delivering presentations, and asking questions of speakers.  We expect them to be bad at it, which is why they are students.

Comment: Focusing on how much the presentation sucks is definitely not helpful and usually leads to bitterness in my experience.  I'm well aware there are bad talks, but my question was about how to manage my own boredom in spite of it all.

Answer (score 0):

During graduate school we had weekly, compulsory seminars. I also struggled with boredom. Often I found the presenter was presenting a set of slides designed for an academic conference rather a weekly seminar primarily to graduates.   My solution was not to go to all (no one bothered despite the compulsory nature) of them but just go to the ones directly relevant to me, that sounded particularly interesting or I knew the speaker was good. If you can get away with it may be worth a try; you can't be expected to find everything useful.

Another tip I employed was never to take my laptop, just a pen and paper. Don't give yourself a chance to be distracted by e-mails / work and it will help in a small way.

Comment: Not going is not an option-- I've already been chastised for missing some.